# Paint a FILL_AND_STROKE form with different colors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

In the [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) class documentation says:

> `enum Paint.Style`:
>
> The Style specifies if the primitive being drawn is filled, stroked, 
>       or both (in the same color).

For `FILL_AND_STROKE`: Is there some way of specifying different color values for the stroke and the fill?

Else whats the point of that value? Just make the text thicker?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that for small size objects "for example: small text size", take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044769/how-to-draw-text-with-diferent-stroke-and-fill-colors-in-android-using-java?answertab=votes#tab-top).